# simple question about css multiple divs

Tags: css, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wall" > 
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <div class="tbr01"><th>Content</th></div> 
    <div class="tbr02"><th>User</th></div> 
    <div class="tbr03"><th>Published</th></div>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

How do i adjust the width of the th div.tbr01

This is what i've tried in my css file: but i am doing something wrong?

```
div.wall table tr div.tbr01 th {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Regards,
Thijs

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. **tr** cannot contain **div**. Maybe when you fix that, everything will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems it doesn't like the div... apply the class to the th or use

```
div.wall table tr th {
    width: 300px;
}
```

OR

```
<div class="wall" > 
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <th class="tbr01">Content</th>
    <th class="tbr02">User</th>
    <th class="tbr03">Published</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

```
div.wall table tr th.tbr01 {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: The explicit tag names in that CSS are redundant.  `.wall .tbr01 { width: 300px; }` would work just as well.

Comment: @WillMartin agreed, but as I usually do, I kept the code as close to the original as possible so as to highlight the differences.  Personally I would use `.tbr01` and not even specify `.wall`.  I doubt he will need to reuse the `.tbr01` class in something other than a `.wall` div.

Comment: Thanks! Now i know that divs can't be apllied to sub elements so a div on a table is valid, but divs to it's children isn't! Nice!

Answer (score 4):

Your HTML is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/).

You cannot have a `<div>` as a child of a `<tr>` or a parent of `<th>`.

Browsers will perform error recovery in various different ways and often give you a DOM that isn't like you expect (e.g. by moving all the div elements outside the table).

Get rid of the div elements and apply your styles directly to the table cells.